# Flutter pods error when building app in Xcode

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this error in Xcode when i try to build my app in Xcode.

```
/Users/Desktop/Flutter/weather/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner')
```

Error appear after i added `geolocator: "^5.0.0"` package before that i was working. Also reverted code to before `geolocator: "^5.0.0"` and work so it looks like problem is with this package

Answer (score 2):

thanks but i think the problem was that cocapods were not installed in ios dir

so i made cd ios and then pod setup

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Open your Xcode project workspace. The path is something similar to:

*{your project}/ios/Runner.xcworkspace*

From Xcode Top Options Menu:

1. **Product** > **Clean Build Folder**
2. Wait for it to process the clean
3. **Product** > **Build**

If this didn't work, close and reopen Xcode and repeat the above

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a missing dependency , go to ios dir and type `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything like deleting the ios directory, derived data and uninstalled Cocoapods but no one is worked for me. At last, I tried to create one new flutter project and tried running it in Simulator but same exception only. So I just reinstalled Flutter SDK and it worked finally.

Comment: cd ios and then pod setup